# Additonal parameters for data task completion handler in Swift

Tags: swift, parameters, completionhandler

I am new to Swift.  When a button is pressed, my view controller calls a method of a web service class.  The method in turn calls dataTask(), and provides a completion handler :

```
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print(error ?? "")
            return
        }

        // print(JSON(data:data!))
        print ("data : ", data ?? "-- no data --")
        print ("response : ", response ?? "-- no response --")
        print ("error : ", error ?? "-- no error --")
```

The completion handler needs to update the GUI of the view controller.  However, the handler seems to take only three standard parameters.  How can the view controller reference be passed into it?  The handler cannot do self.someTextView.update(.....) to update the GUI, because it is in a web service class, not in the view controller.

Any idea?  Thanks.

Comment: add some more code please, I don't know where you put that task

Comment: The closure captures objects and values from the calling method, so use `self` or create a variable with the reference you need before `let task ...`

Comment: Assuming that your view controller has a reference to this web service class, make a delegate or a callback function between them.

Comment: Thanks.  Found a solution.  Passing the view controller reference to the web service class, and keeping it there as an instance variable, for the completion handler to use.

Answer (score 1):

As per mentioned in [dataTask(with:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask):

> This completion handler takes the following parameters:
>
> ```
> data
> ```
>
> The data returned by the server.
>
> ```
> response
> ```
>
> An object that provides response metadata, such as HTTP headers and
>   status code. If you are making an HTTP or HTTPS request, the returned
>   object is actually an HTTPURLResponse object.
>
> ```
> error
> ```
>
> An error object that indicates why the request failed, or nil if the
>   request was successful.

Which means -obviously-, it has nothing to do with a UIViewController.

So, if you would like to include the "ViewController" layer to such a process, you could implement your own wrapper to do such a task, for instance, you could create a function that takes a completion parameter -as an escaping closure-, as follows:

```
func request(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print(error ?? "")
            return
        }

        // print(JSON(data:data!))
        print ("data : ", data ?? "-- no data --")
        print ("response : ", response ?? "-- no response --")
        print ("error : ", error ?? "-- no error --")

        // now you could call the "completion" parameter:
        completion()
    }
}
```

In your view controller, you could call it as:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        request {
            // now you could update your textview:
            self.someTextView.update(.....)
        }

    }
}
```

You could declare the signature of `request` to be satisfied your needs...

Answer (score 0):

You can post a local Notification, which hits a method and that method declared in UIViewController Class.

Here is the Code :

In web Service Class : in Completion Handler :

> NotificationCenter.default.post(name:
>   Notification.Name("Notification_NAME_HERE"), object: nil, userInfo:
>   nil)

In UIViewController Class : in viewDidLoad :

> NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
>    #selector(notificationHandler(notification:)), name: Notification.Name(Notification_NAME_HERE), object: nil)

Add a notificationHandler method into the UIViewController Class :

> func notificationHandler(notification: Notification)
>       {
>           //update ui here
>       }

This method will be hit by Completion Handler, and same time you can update your UI or whatever you want to do into UIViewController Class.

I think this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it, but what about using capture values for it? 
Something like ...

```
...code...
var somevar = 3
....whateverblock { [unowned somevar], (default parameters of the blcok) in
somevar = 4
...code...
}
```

I did not test this, so not sure if it will work.